# Connect to facebook chat using Jabber.net (C#/Mono) with SASL

Tags: c#, xmpp, facebook-chat, sasl

I am trying to connect to facebook chat using Jabber.net(c#/Mono). The code I am using is this:

```
    static ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    const bool VERBOSE = true;
    const string TARGET = "friends_username@chat.facebook.com";

    void Start () 
    {

        JabberClient j = new JabberClient();

        j.User = "my_facebook_alias";  //Later to be removed
        j.Server = "chat.facebook.com"; 
        j.Port = 5222;
        j.NetworkHost = "chat.facebook.com";
        j.AutoStartCompression = true;
        j.KeepAlive = 30F;
        j.AutoStartTLS = false;
        j.AutoStartCompression = true;
        j.PlaintextAuth = true;
        j.Password = "my_facebook_password";  //Later to be removed
        j.RequiresSASL = true;
        j.LocalCertificate = null;
        // don't do extra stuff, please.
        j.AutoPresence = false;
        j.AutoRoster = true;
        j.AutoReconnect = -1;

        j.OnInvalidCertificate += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(j_OnInvalidCertificate);

        // listen for errors.  Always do this!
        j.OnError += new bedrock.ExceptionHandler(j_OnError);

        // what to do when login completes
        j.OnAuthenticate += new bedrock.ObjectHandler(j_OnAuthenticate);

        // listen for XMPP wire protocol
        if (VERBOSE)
        {
            j.OnReadText += new bedrock.TextHandler(j_OnReadText);
            j.OnWriteText += new bedrock.TextHandler(j_OnWriteText);
        }

        // Set everything in motion
        j.Connect();

        // wait until sending a message is complete
        done.WaitOne();

        // logout cleanly
        j.Close();
    }

    static void j_OnWriteText(object sender, string txt)
    {
        if (txt == " ") return;  // ignore keep-alive spaces
        Console.WriteLine("SEND: " + txt);
    }

    static void j_OnReadText(object sender, string txt)
    {
        if (txt == " ") return;  // ignore keep-alive spaces
        Console.WriteLine("RECV: " + txt);
    }

    static void j_OnAuthenticate(object sender)
    {
        Debug.Log ("OnAuth...");
        // Sender is always the JabberClient.
        JabberClient j = (JabberClient)sender;
        j.Message(TARGET, "My test message!!!");

        // Finished sending.  Shut down.
        done.Set();
    }

    static void j_OnError(object sender, Exception ex)
    {
        // There was an error!
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        Debug.Log ("Error: "+ex.ToString());
        // Shut down.
        done.Set();
    }

    bool j_OnInvalidCertificate(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        Debug.Log("Invalid certificate "+sslPolicyErrors.ToString() +" : "+certificate.ToString(true));

        return true;
    }
```

I get to j_OnAuthenticate which is good. And it uses my id/password, since changing password to something else makes an error appear. However I do want to use X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL mechanism to be able to login without saving the users id/password.

The full log is:

```
RECV: <?xml version="1.0"?><stream:stream id="E34678B6" from="chat.facebook.com" version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xml:lang="en">
RECV: <stream:features><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms></stream:features>
SEND: <auth mechanism="DIGEST-MD5" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" />
RECV: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cmVhbG09ImNoYXQuZmFjZWJvb2suY29tIixub25jZT0iMDBENjAwQ0UyNjZBNzgyMEE5MUIzRDhGNjZDODQ1QjMiLHFvcD0iYXV0aCIsY2hhcnNldD11dGYtOCxhbGdvcml0aG09bWQ1LXNlc3M=</challenge>
SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dXNlcm5hbWU9ImpvbmFzMiIscmVhbG09ImNoYXQuZmFjZWJvb2suY29tIixub25jZT0iMDBENjAwQ0UyNjZBNzgyMEE5MUIzRDhGNjZDODQ1QjMiLGNub25jZT0iMzUzMzMyM2E2YTZmNmU2MTczMzIzYTUxNGU1ZjQxNjI0YzM4NjYiLG5jPTAwMDAwMDAxLHFvcD1hdXRoLGRpZ2VzdC11cmk9InhtcHAvY2hhdC5mYWNlYm9vay5jb20iLHJlc3BvbnNlPTcxN2ExNjM0MzdjOWU5MDM2NDcwYjViNTBhOTYxODIxLGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTg=</response>
RECV: <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cnNwYXV0aD1hM2ZlZGM1NGRmYzNmMGEzMTU5Y2EyZDVmMmVkMmE2Zg==</challenge>
SEND: <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" />
RECV: <success xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"/>
SEND: <stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" id="10996e3a" xmlns="jabber:client" to="chat.facebook.com" version="1.0">
RECV: <?xml version="1.0"?><stream:stream id="2AF2D483" from="chat.facebook.com" version="1.0" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xml:lang="en">
RECV: <stream:features><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"/><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></stream:features>
SEND: <iq id="JN_1" type="set" to="chat.facebook.com"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><resource>Jabber.Net</resource></bind></iq>
RECV: <iq id="JN_1" type="result"><bind xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-bind"><jid>jonas2@chat.facebook.com/Jabber.Net_c938c6a2_4C7D6EF9DCFDC</jid></bind></iq>
SEND: <iq id="JN_2" type="set" to="chat.facebook.com"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session" /></iq>
RECV: <iq type="result" from="chat.facebook.com" id="JN_2"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>
OnAuth...
SEND: <message id="JN_3" type="chat" to="friends_username@chat.facebook.com"><body>My test message!!!</body></message>
SEND: <presence type="unavailable"><status>offline</status></presence>
SEND: </stream:stream>
SEND: <iq id="JN_4" type="get"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:roster" /></iq>
```

In MatriX XMPP there is a OnBeforeSasl delegate where a custom method can setup the required facebook Sasl properties (like facebook app id, app secret and access token). But there is no such delegate in Jabber.net!

Is there no SASL support i Jabber.net? Or how do you set it up?

Comment: I should also mention that the message never gets delivered. So neither X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM or DIGEST-MD5 works at the moment :(

Comment: is this code for web application or desktop application?
because jabber-net is for only desktop application

Comment: It's for a mobile device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is SASL support in jabber-net, but there is no support for the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL mechanism. If you want to use this mechanism you have to extend jabber-net by adding this SASL mechanism.

Facebook is closing the XMPP connection. This can be related to the message you send in the Authenticate event. Try to send your message after jabber-net sent your initial presence, or after you got your roster.

Alex