# How to send private messages with Facebook API using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, xmpp, facebook-chat

I use Facebook Connect for login on my website and need to create functionality of sending personal messages to user's Facebook friends.

A solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574431/facebook-api-send-private-messages-to-friends) is not suitable for me because I need to send messages to several friends at the same time (user just selects friends from the list who she/he wants to send a message).

I've found pretty good post about this question for Ruby - [How to send private messages with Facebook API](http://dalibornasevic.com/posts/35-how-to-send-private-messages-with-facebook-api). But I can't find a C# package similar to xmpp4r_facebook Ruby gem.

[agsXMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/) and [jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/) don't support X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL mechanism (http://forum.ag-software.de/thread/1372-Facebook-Chat and [Connect to facebook chat using Jabber.net (C#/Mono) with SASL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069401/connect-to-facebook-chat-using-jabber-net-c-mono-with-sasl)).

I hope to find some existing solution instead of updating one of these libraries. Or to find some library like xmpp4r_facebook but for .NET platform.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The latest sources of agsXMPP supports the  X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM Sasl mechanism.

1) checkout the latest sources
2) add the following code to the OnSaslStart event

```
private void XmppCon_OnSaslStart(object sender, SaslEventArgs args)
{
   args.Mechanism = Mechanism.GetMechanismName(agsXMPP.protocol.sasl.MechanismType.X_FACEBOOK_PLATFORM);
   args.ExtentedData = new FacebookExtendedData {AccessToken = "YOUR TOKEN", ApiKey = "YOUR API KEY"};    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not allow the SDK to send private messages to prevent misuse by spammers